# Getting error on npm install as npm ERR cb() never called

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-start

I have set a proxy in npm global config. On installing any package I am getting following error. 
Below is my node and npm version:
npm: 6.13.4
node: v12.16.1

As I am behind proxy, what else is required to overcome this issue. Every help will be appreciated.
I have also tried by updating node version, removing and after restart setting proxy again, but none of that worked.

```
    C:\test>npm i level-db-helper
    npm ERR! cb() never called!

    npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
    npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-03T04_51_02_995Z-debug.log

    C:\test>npm get proxy
    http://my-proxy.com:8080

    C:\test>npm get https-proxy
    http://my-proxy.com:8080

    C:\test>
```

Below is my log file content

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'i',
1 verbose cli   'level-db-helper'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose npm-session b2d05546852e6399
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 timing npm Completed in 3615ms
8 error cb() never called!
9 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
10 error <https://npm.community>
```

Answer (score 8):

Finally I found the culprit of this issue by my own research, It was due to inaccessible proxy url, so after changing the npm proxy and https-proxy by following command I resolved this issue.

(You need administrative rights to execute this command)

```
npm config set proxy http://your-proxy-url.com:PORT_NUMBER
npm config set https-proxy http://your-proxy-url.com:PORT_NUMBER
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was because DNS stopped working for some reason, pinging google.com returned a "temporary failure in name resolution" message. I updated the network configuration and it sorted the issue.

Comment: I was also behind a proxy and didn't realize it. Switching internet connections fixed for me.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error when, npm install from docker.
deleted the un-used docker images, using the following commands

```
docker image prune
docker image rm <imageId>
```

It solved the issue for me

Comment: I'm stuck with the same issue. But, when I tried listing images, I don't see anything. Wondering what else is causing this.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons for this issue is that you have `package-lock.json` file in your project directory. So, you may have to delete or rename the `package-lock.json` file from the directory and then run the `npm install` command. Best option is to delete this file.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: The package-lock.json has a purpose. So, deleting it is not a solution.

Comment: The package-lock.json file should be added to source control for installing same dependencies exactly to the same version which development team used for development. If you delete the package file and run  "npm install " again the current matched version of dependencies will be installd acourding the semantic versioning specified in the  "Package.json" file.